# Make Ace the highest rank card in a deck of cards

Tags: c#

I have created this Card game, it works good, but I haven't being able to make the Ace the highest ranked card. Every time a player has ACE, he lost to the other player, and I can't figure out how to make this work correctly. I tried to use in the first statement `if (c1.Value > c2.Value || c.Value=="Ace")` and it didn't work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PTCB12WARGAME2
{

    class Card
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Value;
        public string Suit;
        public override string ToString() { return string.Format("{0} of {1}", Name, Suit); }
    }
    class DeckOfCards
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<Card> DeckOfCards = new List<Card>()
                {
                    new Card { Name="Ace", Value=1, Suit="Heart"},
                    new Card{Name="two",Value=2,Suit="Heart"},
                    new Card{Name="three",Value=3,Suit="Heart"},
                    new Card{Name="four",Value=4,Suit="Heart"},
                    new Card { Name="five", Value=5, Suit="Heart"},
                    new Card{Name="six",Value=6,Suit="Heart"},
                    new Card{Name="seven",Value=7,Suit="Heart"},
                    new Card{Name="eight",Value=8,Suit="Heart"},
                    new Card { Name="Nine", Value=9, Suit="heart"},
                    new Card{Name="ten",Value=10,Suit="Heart"},
                    new Card{Name="jack",Value=11,Suit="Heart"},
                    new Card{Name="queen",Value=12,Suit="Heart"},
                    new Card { Name="king", Value=13, Suit="heart"},
                    new Card { Name="Ace", Value=1, Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card{Name="two",Value=2,Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card{Name="three",Value=3,Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card{Name="four",Value=4,Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card { Name="five", Value=5, Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card{Name="six",Value=6,Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card{Name="seven",Value=7,Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card{Name="eight",Value=8,Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card { Name="Nine", Value=9, Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card{Name="ten",Value=10,Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card{Name="jack",Value=11,Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card{Name="queen",Value=12,Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card { Name="king", Value=13, Suit="Spades"},
                    new Card { Name="Ace", Value=1, Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card{Name="two",Value=2,Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card{Name="three",Value=3,Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card{Name="four",Value=4,Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card { Name="five", Value=5, Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card{Name="six",Value=6,Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card{Name="seven",Value=7,Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card{Name="eight",Value=8,Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card { Name="Nine", Value=9, Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card{Name="ten",Value=10,Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card{Name="jack",Value=11,Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card{Name="queen",Value=12,Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card { Name="king", Value=13, Suit="Diamonds"},
                    new Card { Name="Ace", Value=1, Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card{Name="two",Value=2,Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card{Name="three",Value=3,Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card{Name="four",Value=4,Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card { Name="five", Value=5, Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card{Name="six",Value=6,Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card{Name="seven",Value=7,Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card{Name="eight",Value=8,Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card { Name="Nine", Value=9, Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card{Name="ten",Value=10,Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card{Name="jack",Value=11,Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card{Name="queen",Value=12,Suit="Clubs"},
                    new Card { Name="king", Value=13, Suit="Clubs"},

                };
        
            Console.WriteLine("Each player is flipping over 1 card and whomever has the highest card wins");
            Console.ReadLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < DeckOfCards.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DeckOfCards[i]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();         
            Random random = new Random();

            List<Card> deckOfPlayer1 = new List<Card>();
            List<Card> deckOfPlayer2 = new List<Card>();

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Let's flip cards");
                string userAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
                if (userAnswer == "quit")
                    break;             
                int r1;
                r1 = random.Next(0, DeckOfCards.Count);
                Card c1 = DeckOfCards[r1];
                deckOfPlayer1.Add(c1);              
                DeckOfCards.RemoveAt(r1);

                int r2;
                r2 = random.Next(0, DeckOfCards.Count);
                Card c2 = DeckOfCards[r2];
                deckOfPlayer2.Add(c2);
            
                DeckOfCards.RemoveAt(r2);

                Console.WriteLine("Player1 has: {0}", c1);
                Console.WriteLine("Player2 has: {0}", c2);

                if (c1.Value > c2.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player1 wins");
                }
                else if (c1.Value < c2.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player2 wins");
                }
                else if (c1.Value == c2.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Its a tie! Next three card in deck are played face down, 4th card face up," +
                        "woemer has the highest card wins");
                }
            } while (DeckOfCards.Count > 0);

        }
    }
}

I
```

Comment: I removed all of the nonsense tags you used and added the single relevant tag you didn't bother to add. Please don't just throw random words into tags or grab things that aren't meaningful or relevant. Tag spamming is a good way to get quick downvotes.

Comment: Thank you, Mr White. Sorry, I am new in this website. I will learn to use Tag Spamming to avoid nonsense tags. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you make ace value 14 for this game? Or add another property Rank and give ace the highest rank?

Comment: Good morning, Jesse de Wit, sorry, I am new in this world of coding. What does "make ace value 14" mean, please? So, is there a property called rank? Ok, I will try it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I was trying to say in the comments is, in a case like this it's helpful to test for equality first, then test for one value greater than the other. If neither of those are true, then the `else` case handles the last possible state without needing a test condition.

As far as testing for the Ace is concerned, you can either special-case a condition to check for its value, or give it the highest value in the first place (instead of the lowest).

For example:

```
if (c1.Value == c2.Value)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Its a tie! Next three card in deck are played face down, " + 
        "4th card face up, whoever has the highest card wins");
}
else if (c1.Value == 1 || (c1.Value > c2.Value && c2.Value != 1))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Player1 wins");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Player2 wins");
}
```

---

As a side note, you can shorten your code a lot if you create an array of names and an array of suits, as you can simply use nested loops to populate your deck of cards list:

```
var names = new [] { "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", 
     "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };

var suits = new [] { "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Spades" };

var cards = new List<Card>();

// Populate our deck of cards with two nested loops
foreach(var suit in suits)
{
    // We use a 'for' loop here instead of 'foreach' so we can use the index to 
    // populate the Value (which is always one more than the index of the name)
    for(int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
    {
        cards.Add(new Card { Name = names[i], Value = i + 1, Suit = suit });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Rufus L, you are right, I followed your advice to shorten my code a lot by creating an array of names and an array of suits.

Answer (score 0):

How does this look? (Edited down the code)

```
if (c1.Value == c2.Value) {
    //Tie
}
else if (c1.Value ==1) {
    //c1 wins
}
else if (c2.Value == 1) {
    //c2 wins
}
else if (c1.Value > c2.Value) {
    //c1 wins
}
else {
    //c2 wins
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Luke Weaver, it worked! I had forgot that Ace equal number 1 in my code.